# Magento don't save custom order of categories on admin?

Tags: magento

In magento 1.6 i want to sort manually the categories order *(categories - manage categories)*, when the page is ready, i do drag and drop whith the category but after ajax saved if i refresh the page the order change, i look around but i dont have find nothing.
I try also, tried to reindex data but nothing change, why dont work?

Comment: Your question isn't programming related and should not be on SO. Try ServerFault.com?

Comment: You need to ensure that the category hierarchy is correct in the database. Were these categories manipulated directly in the DB or imported at any point? Check that sort orders are sequential.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Magento PE a while back.  One thing that helped us was to turn of automatic indexing.  Under `Admin -> System -> Index Management` Click the "Select All" and choose "Change Index Mode".  Select "Manual Update" and click Submit.

Go to the `Catalog -> Manage Categories` section again and move your categories around.  Navigate away from the page then come back to ensure that they keep their locations.  Go to the Index Management screen again and refresh everything.

When I was experiencing this problem in PE, I turned on sql query logging.  Magento appeared to have much less database activity with the indexes set to "Manual Update" as opposed to   "Update on Save".

hth